# Unable to edit .ipynb files in Gateway

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jetbrains-ide, jetbrains-gateway

Unlike in PyCharm, there's no plugin for Jupyter Notebook in Gateway. Is there a way to edit and run `.ipynb` files in this IDE?

For context: I work through GitPod.

I wanted to use the plugin for IntelliJ, but it's unavailable for Gateway.